# Load Excel with Check box (form control) using SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis

I have to load unstructured excel file  into temp table , think of it as a survey form with check boxes (form control) .

My problem is check box value does not come if I covert excel into CSV or any another format.

Can I use SSIS to load this excel file or How can load this file so that check box value is also captured.

Comment: How do I add a form control to an Excel spreadsheet? My guess is that the checkbox is nothing the default connection manager will "see." If that's the case, then you might need something like a hidden worksheet that extracts the value of the checkbox into a "normal" cell.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can obtain the value of the checkbox by referring to the cell in the `Cell Link` property of the control. (See [the Office documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-check-box-option-button-or-toggle-button-to-a-worksheet-HP010236677.aspx#BMadd_or_edit_a_check_box_%28forms_toolba) for details on determining that cell reference.)

However, it sounds like that's not set in your case. If so, you're **not** going to be able to access that checkbox through the SSIS Excel connection manager. You'll have to write code to walk through the Excel object model and get the value that way.